# how to use auto sandbox in avast 6

Tags: sandbox

how to use auto sandbox in avast 6? Is this automatic? If you launch an executable file is it automatically contained in the sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the manual page about avast v6 auto sandboxing:

> https://support.avast.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=602&nav=0